# In Next JS 13 using app router - How can I change the state of a component in the root layout from its children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am upgrading a Next JS app project to use the App Router.

The layout.js (root layout) has a Logo component that will be displayed on all routes.

In the RootLayout I maintain a state variable to update the appearance (className) of the Logo component as soon as a child component is requesting.

In the past when using the page router, this could be achieved by passing the function to set the state within the  tags.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Logo className={` ${isLoading ? "draw" : ""} ${hideLogo ? "hide" : ""}`}>
      <Component {...pageProps} setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />
    </Logo>
  )
}
```

The updated version with App Router looks like this:

```
"use client"
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [hideLogo, setHideLogo] = useState(false)
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Logo
          className={`${isLoading} ? "draw" : ""} ${hideLogo ? "hide" : ""}`}
        ></Logo>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

What can I do with the updated App Router to achieve the same functionality?

I have found no documentation on how to make this work, however I'm thinking that this use-case is somewhat common and there are people out there who can suggest a best practice approach.

Comment: Doesn't answer your specific question. But app router has a loading.js file for showing loading UI between routes now. 

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming

Answer (score 0):

First, you layouts should be server component. 
If you are using state in your component you need to add "use client" which make it not a server component

I'm had a similar issue. 
you can do: /
An object that contains information per path name:

```
const PATHS = {
 "/search": {
"logo" : "SOME COOL LOGO",
"backgroundColor": "COOL COLOR"
 }
}
```

to get the path follow this: [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/43657#discussioncomment-5981981)

**Note:** you don't need to specify for every route, only those you want to change the default look.

use these values as the logo url, but always have some fall case values

Comment: I have looked through the github issue but can't seem to find anything related to my problem. Maybe you can suggest a code example?